# How to include the "+" (must include) search operator in a lynx command line bing/google search query

Tags: bing, lynx

I'm using Lynx to scrape Bing search results and having trouble incorporating into the command line the "+" operator that in Bing (and Google) signifies "must have" in search results.

E.g. the bing URL for searching for "+mango" is:
https://www.bing.com/search?q=%2Bmango&qs=n&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=%2Bmango&sc=0-6&sk=&cvid=3F29F41FFFD84260941167DBE02F3E85

The "+" gets converted to "%2B". Fine. However, if I develop a lynx command around this to scrape the result, neither using "%2B" nor using "+" works. The "%2B" is not interpreted correctly or as it would be if you pasted the whole URL into a browser URL bar, and the "+" function is not interpreted correctly either.

The lynx command should be
lynx -dump "https://www.bing.com/search?q=%2Bmango&qs=n&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=%2Bmango&sc=0-6&sk=&cvid=3F29F41FFFD84260941167DBE02F3E85" -nolist > output.txt

But it doesn't work, and putting the "+" in place of the "%2B" doesn't work either, because it is then interpreted as a space (spaces get converted to "+" in these expressions). Wrapping quotation marks around the plus sign also doesn't work, unsurprisingly, since the quote marks have a different function in the expression there.

Wondering if there is some sort of "escape character" in the lynx world, or some other way to hardcode a "+" into the expression ?

Using Windows.

Comment: You should use Bing APIs to consume results:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/directory/search/.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, I'm aware of Bing APIs. That wasn't relevant to my question though. I have my own reasons for wanting to use lynx: partly cost, partly ease of use.